# send binary files from php to mysql using mysqli

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

i want to send data into two tables from a php script,the `pic` and `idcard` are two binary files that in mysql db and both of them have `LONGBLOB` type always the first insert query executed successfully(insert into `user` table) but the second query(insert into `applicant' table) have two situations:

1-if i make the  `pic` and `idcard` field NULLABLE in db,other data except these two inserted successfully.

2-if i make the  `pic` and `idcard` field NOT NULLABLE nothing insert into `applicant' table.

and both of two situation i cant save the binary data into my database,where is the problem?

and i also have no problem in $_FILES array and passing them,i can see the details of these fileds when i post it to the php script.
i think something is wrong with the `send_long_data` but i use it before exactly like now!

here is the script:

```
require_once('db_connection_config.php');
if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
    print_r("<div class='bs-example center-block'><div id='alertshow' class='bs-example center-block alert alert-danger'><a href='#' class='close' data-dismiss='alert'>&times;</a><strong>Connection Error:</strong>" . mysqli_connect_errno() . "</div></div>");
    exit();
}
$today = date('Y:m:d');

$pass = randomPassword();

$stmt = $mysqli->prepare("INSERT INTO user (password,gender,firstname,lastname,email,phoneNum,mobileNum,Address,UserRoles_userRoleId) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,3)");
$stmt->bind_param("sissssss", $pass, $_POST['gender'], $_POST['name'], $_POST['lastname'], $_POST['email'], $_POST['phonenum'], $_POST['mobilenum'], $_POST['address']);
$stmt->execute();

$mkey = mysqli_insert_id($mysqli);

$stmt->close();

if(isset($_FILES['pic']) && isset($_FILES['idcard'])){
$pic_file_path = $_FILES['pic']['tmp_name'];
    if ( !file_exists($pic_file_path) ) {
        throw new Exception('File not found.');
    }
$pic_handle = fopen($pic_file_path, "rb");
    if ( !$pic_handle ) {
        throw new Exception('File open failed.');
    }
    $pic_content = null;

$idpic_file_path = $_FILES['idcard']['tmp_name'];
$idpic_handle = fopen($idpic_file_path, "rb");
$idpic_content = null;

$stmt = $mysqli->prepare("INSERT INTO applicant (userId,nationalCode,fatherName,birthPlace,nationality,religion,postalCode,picture,idpicture,registrationDate,militaryServiceStatus) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)");
$stmt->bind_param("isssiisbbss", $mkey, $_POST['nationalcode'], $_POST['fathername'], $_POST['birthcity'], $_POST['nationality'], $_POST['religion'], $_POST['postalcode'], $pic_content, $idpic_content, $today, $_POST['mss']);
while (!feof($pic_handle)) {
    $stmt->send_long_data(1, fread($pic_handle, 8192));
}
fclose($pic_handle);
while (!feof($idpic_handle)) {
    $stmt->send_long_data(1, fread($idpic_handle, 8192));
}
fclose($idpic_handle);
$stmt->execute();
$stmt->close();
}


}

function randomPassword() {
    $alphabet = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUWXYZ0123456789";
    $pass = array(); //remember to declare $pass as an array
    $alphaLength = strlen($alphabet) - 1; //put the length -1 in cache
    for ($i = 0; $i < 8; $i++) {
        $n = rand(0, $alphaLength);
        $pass[] = $alphabet[$n];
    }
    return implode($pass); //turn the array into a string
}
```

Comment: Whenever possible avoid storing files in the database. A really good idea is to store the files in some folder and, in the database, store the path to the file itself.

Comment: Please add (extensive) error handling to your script. fopen may fail, all of the mysqli function/method may fail - check them all.

Comment: @VolkerK
fopen is just fine,why the source of problem should be that?i'll use it many many times just like this!

Comment: @Andrew
you're right,but i've to do this just here,and i wonder where is my fault!?

Comment: "why the source of error should be that" - why shouldn't it be? Can you prove otherwise? Yes you can - with error handling code - which is an excellent idea when looking for an error you don't know where it happens. Add error handling.

Comment: and don't forget to check whether the while(!feof... loops have been entered at least once per file handle ;-)

Comment: @VolkerK
i add some error checking on fopen,and no Exception thrown from that.

Comment: you put file data into the nationalCode field (1)

Comment: @Deadooshka
the second parameter in bind param is `$_POST['nationalcode']` and the second field in `$stmt` also is `nationalCode`,what!?!!!

Comment: why is `$_POST['nationalcode']` there instead of `null`?

Comment: @Deadooshka
i do double check on that,and can not found what you said!
the null is in `$idpic_content = null` and `    $pic_content = null`...

Comment: send_long_data first parameters must be 7 and 8 respectively, not 1.

Comment: tnx, you saved me!my bad!